# How to generate a double tap using MotionEvent

Tags: java, android, touch-event, double-click, motionevent

I'm trying to generate a double tap using `MotionEvent` so I can trick a view into thinking a double tap occurred, but it's not working. `Zoomageview` is an imported implementation from https://github.com/jsibbold/zoomage, which gives an `ImageView` zooming capabilities. Double tap is a zoom feature of `ZoomageView`, but I want to programmatically specify an x and y coordinate it should zoom in on.

Edit: I forgot to mention `ZoomageView` extends `AppCompatImageView`.

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
                    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                    v.getX(),
                    v.getY(),
                    0
            );
            zoomageView.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);

            motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
                    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
                    v.getX(),
                    v.getY(),
                    0
            );
            zoomageView.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
           motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
                    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                    v.getX(),
                    v.getY(),
                    0
            );
            zoomageView.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
                    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
                    v.getX(),
                    v.getY(),
                    0
            );
            zoomageView.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I just needed to increase the value returned by SystemClock.uptimeMillis().

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
                SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                v.getX(),
                v.getY(),
                0
        );
        zoomageView.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);

        motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
                SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 200,
                SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 300,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
                v.getX(),
                v.getY(),
                0
        );
        zoomageView.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
       motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
                SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 400,
                SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 500,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                v.getX(),
                v.getY(),
                0
        );
        zoomageView.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
                SystemClock.uptimeMillis()  + 600,
                SystemClock.uptimeMillis()  + 700,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
                v.getX(),
                v.getY(),
                0
        );
        zoomageView.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }
})
```